# Stopping an AWS EC2 Instance through HTML/Python/Bash Script

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there any way to send a button/hyperlink in an email through HTML which will trigger a Python/Bash Script which will stop a running EC2 instance ?

I am basically going through all running instances, checking their uptime through **Fabric -> SSH** and then sending a mail when the uptime has been beyond a specified limit.

If it is not possible through a script, is there a specific **hyperlink** for every instance which triggers its stopping ?

**PS:** I know about Amazon CloudWatch but am searching for an alternative since I would have to create an alarm for every instance manually through cloudwatch.

**PS-2:** I don't require the whole code. Any help in this direction will be appreciated. 

Example : What frameworks can be used ? etc.

Comment: Please use boto for this: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/

Comment: I know how to use boto for stopping instances but is there any way to use boto to create multiple cloudwatch alarms for multiple instances?

Comment: @DarthShadow Do you need to stop instances that are running for less than specified interval or greater than the specified interval? Is the interval threshold hardcoded or it's different on any given day?

Comment: Greater than specified interval and the interval can be assumed to be hardcoded

Comment: check out this tutorial (http://aameer.github.io/cloud-computing-101/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For handling amazon instances you probably want to use `boto` which provides most of the common needed functionality. It is very important to read the documentation since data loss is a possibility. Consider starting [**here**](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#amazon-ec2).

To figure out how long the instance was running you can use [`instance.launch_time`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.launch_time).

To stop an instance you can use [`instance.stop`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.stophttps://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.stop):

> Stops an Amazon EBS-backed instance. Each time you transition an instance from stopped to started, Amazon EC2 charges a full instance hour, even if transitions happen multiple times within a single hour.
>
> You can't start or stop Spot Instances. (more in link...)

To terminate an instance use [`instance.terminate`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.terminate):

> Shuts down one or more instances. This operation is idempotent; if you terminate an instance more than once, each call succeeds.
>
> By default, Amazon EC2 deletes all EBS volumes that were attached when the instance launched. Volumes attached after instance launch continue running.

Comment: I already know how to use boto for starting and stopping instances. I want to know if there is a way to stop multiple instances when they have been running for a specified time.

Comment: You can use boto to know how long they were running: https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.launch_time

Comment: Do you mean the `instance.launch_time` attribute?

Comment: Yes. Note that this is probably not creation time.

Comment: The documentation regarding exactly what time this gives is vague. It could be the first time it was launched or the time it was created or hopefully what I need i.e. the current launch time. It is definitely one possible way of doing it. But is there no way that an instance can be terminated through the response to an email?